# Different learnings in different countries

Tags: knowledge, pattern, geography

> I learnt ***Skiing*** in my ***1st attempt*** in ***Finland*** when the time was ***5 o'clock***

---

> I learnt ***Diving*** in my ***5th attempt*** in ***Uruguay*** when the time was ***6 o'clock***

---

> I learnt ***Boxing*** in my ***10th attempt*** in ***Luxembourg*** when the time was ***7 o'clock***

---

> I learnt ***Tiling*** in my ***50th attempt*** in ***Honduras*** when the time was ***7 o'clock***

---

> I learnt ***Racing*** in my ***100th attempt*** in ***Australia*** when the time was ***4 o'clock***

---

> I learnt ***Aiding*** in my ***500th attempt*** in ***________*** when the time was ***7 o'clock***

---

> I learnt ***Gaming*** in my ***1000th attempt*** in ***_________*** when the time was ***9 o'clock***

---

***Which two countries fill up the blanks?***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two blanks can be filled by:

> **Ethiopia** and **Guatemala**.

Let's dissect the patterns here...

> The first pattern to note is that the last letter before 'ing' in the activity name is the Roman numeral of the number of the attempt: sk**I**ing (1), di**V**ing (5), bo**X**ing (10), ti**L**ing (50), ra**C**ing (100), ai**D**ing (500), ga**M**ing (1000). However, this is purely for construction purposes - it plays no real further role in the solution process...
>
>  What *is* significant, however, is the relationship between (i) the source word for the activity without the 'ing' (adding an 'e' when necessary, for DIVE, TILE, RACE and GAME), (ii) the *capital city* of the country, and (iii) the time. Specifically, in each instance: when you **remove the letters of the source word from the name of the capital city**, you are left with **the same number of letters as the time** mentioned. Like so:
>
>  Skiing, Finland, 5 o'clock: HEL[S]IN[KI] - SKI = 5 letters;
>  Diving, Uruguay, 6 o'clock: MONT[EVID]EO - DIVE = 6 letters;
>  Boxing, Luxembourg, 7 o'clock: LU[X]EM[BO]URG - BOX = 7 letters;
>  Tiling, Honduras, 7 o'clock: [TE]GUC[I]GA[L]PA - TILE = 7 letters;
>  Racing, Australia, 4 o'clock: [C]ANB[E]R[RA] - RACE = 4 letters.

What we therefore need to find are...

> ...countries whose capital cities leave 7 and 9 letters once AID and GAME are removed from their names, respectively.
>
>  The only sovereign states which satisfy these criteria are:
>
>  **ETHIOPIA**: [AD]D[I]S ABABA - AID = 7 letters;
>  **GUATEMALA**: [G]U[A]T[EM]ALA CITY - GAME = 9 letters.